# How to get the Firefox search suggestions in the firefrox url bar?

Tags: firefox

How can I get firefox search suggestion in the firefox url bar?

> Firefox | Search Or Enter Address

This is the same feature as in Firefox For Android, I can type something, get some suggestions, and choose which search engine I want to use to search that input with.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Visit the URL `about:preferences#search` in your Firefox browser (or navigate there through your menu: <kbd>Edit</kbd> → <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Search</kbd>).

You will see a section like the one below. Make sure **both checkboxes are checked** to get search suggestions in the location bar.
[image]

Comment: This does not work for me? It doesn't display the `Search for {name} with:`?

Comment: @blade19899 You need to click on the magnifying glass at the right hand end of the url location edit box first to choose a non-default search engine.

Comment: @DavidPostill Whut?

Comment: @blade19899 http://i.imgur.com/fDlrFsS.png Pick a search engine and it will use it for the next search.

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't have that? I am on Mozilla Firefox Version `44.0.2`

Comment: @blade19899 Hmm. So am I.

Comment: @blade19899 I am on 44.0.2 on Ubuntu 15.10 as well and there it is. In the search preferences, do you have more than one engine in the "One-click search engines" list and are they enabled (ticked)?

Comment: I only enabled Google and DuckDuckGo

Comment: So where exactly do you miss what? You should see suggestions and be able to select a search engine both in the search bar and on the home page. There should be search suggestions (and probably suggestions from your history) but no icons to select an engine from the URL/location bar. How does yours differ from that?